# Search column for a string return next columns value

Tags: excel

say i have this

```
B1                     C1
TRIGGER 
StartOfTurn             1
AfterCasting            2
BeforeAttack            3
AfterAttack             4
Death                   5
RecivedDamage           6
BeforeReciveDamage      7
```

I need a function that would search B1 for some text and then return the value next to it. Thus if it found "Death" it would return 5

Comment: Didn't you try `Vlookup()`

Comment: was not sure that would work with strings, also if it is not found would that give an NA value in the return cell?  Thus when exported to a db, it would give an NA value to db?  I will try it thought, never knew it was an option

Comment: Use it with `If` and `IsError()` or `IFError()` in case you have xl2007+ Lot of examples can be found in stackoverflow

Comment: ok that would work, sorry not used excel that much.  Now when i put in the function its not working, you see anything wrong? `=VLOOKUP('Card Actions'!B2,Actions!B1:B8,Actions!C:C,FALSE)`

Comment: the above should put the value in B2 , search B1:C8 for the value and return the value in C but instead of the value returning , its returning the string it found

Comment: It would be: `=VLOOKUP('Card Actions'!B2,Actions!B:C,2,FALSE)`. The 'table' has to contain everything; index and values to return. The col index is an positive integer, and it's the 2nd with the index column as the 1st.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, just a couple of things to change and the formula would become:

```
=VLOOKUP('Card Actions'!B2,Actions!B:C,2,FALSE)
```

`VLOOKUP` takes several arguments:

1. Lookup value: You got this right. This is the 'text' that will be looked up in the table.
2. Table: This must contain the column containing the indices **and** the values you want to return. Since you want the values from column C, you need to have `B:C` (or `B1:C8`).
3. Column index number: This is the number of the column from which the result will be extracted from, the index column being the first. So B is 1, C becomes 2.
4. Range lookup (optional): This determines what 'mode' of lookup will be used. `FALSE` or `0` means an exact match of the lookup value and the indices from the table will be attempted. `TRUE` or `1` or when omitted means an approximate match will be attempted instead.